# Perl to Python Function translation

Tags: python, perl, translate

I am trying to translate a Perl function into a Python function, but I am having trouble figuring out what some of the Perl to Python function equivalents.

Perl function:

```
sub reverse_hex {

 my $HEXDATE = shift;
 my @bytearry=();
 my $byte_cnt = 0;
 my $max_byte_cnt = 8;
 my $byte_offset = 0;
 while($byte_cnt < $max_byte_cnt) {
   my $tmp_str = substr($HEXDATE,$byte_offset,2);
    push(@bytearry,$tmp_str);
   $byte_cnt++;
   $byte_offset+=2;
 }
   return join('',reverse(@bytearry));
}
```

I am not sure what "push", "shift", and "substr" are doing here that would be the same in Python.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand what `push`, `shift` and `substr` _do_ in Perl?  If not, the place to start is to understand what they do and then look for equivalents in Python.

Comment: Yeah, apparently shift will take the first byte of the input. substr will takes parts of a string? And push will append data to an array/list it seems.

Comment: No, that's not what `shift` is doing. `shift` is being used to take the first item from an array called `@_`. If you read [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) you'll find out what that array is, and why the first item on it might be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perl subroutine seems rather complicated for what it does, viz., taking chunks of two chars at a time (the first 16 chars) from the sent string and then reverses it.  Another Perl option is:

```
sub reverse_hex {
    return join '', reverse unpack 'A2' x 8, $_[0];
}
```

First, `unpack` here takes two characters at a time (eight times) and produces a list.  That list is `reverse`d and `join`ed to produce the final string.

Here's a Python subroutine to accomplish this:

```
def reverse_hex(HEXDATE):
    hexVals = [HEXDATE[i:i + 2] for i in xrange(0, 16, 2)]
    reversedHexVals = hexVals[::-1]
    return ''.join(reversedHexVals)
```

The list comprehension produces eight elements of two characters each.  `[::-1]` reverses the list's elements and the result is `join`ed and returned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you are asking about the perl to python translation, but if you have any control over the perl, I would like to point out that this function is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

The entire thing could be replaced with:

```
sub reverse_hex
{
  my $hexdate = shift;
  my @bytes = $hexdate =~ /../g;  # break $hexdate into array of character pairs
  return join '', reverse(@bytes);
}
```

Not only is this shorter, it is much easier to get your head around.
Of course, if you have no control over the perl, you are stuck with what you were dealt.

Comment: Chris Charley and I both picked up on the fact that your perl is too complicated.  His approach assumes that the input value is a valid hexadecimal string.  Mine does not.  His approach is much more sophisticated (and probably more efficient) if the input is valid hex.  My approach replicates the behavior of the input function even if the input is invalid hex.   In both our solutions, we have ignored the 8 byte restriction and have simply reversed whatever number of bytes (or character pairs) were provided

Comment: This helps, but it doesn't get what I need. If you throw "cdc4b28e1504ca01" against the Perl sub routine, it will return "128920029968385229" back. With the def you gave me, it will return the reverse value of HEXDATE. 
How are they getting the long from the sub routine?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment when I saw I didn't understand it completely.

Comment: Mike, your Perl function works great and is much more efficient than the original version. Cudos to you on that one! Now I just need to make an equivalent Python function. Can you give me an overview of what exactly it's doing so I can come up with one? I am not as familiar with Perl.

Comment: @ChangoMango: Your question has been marked down and put on hold because you appear to have made no effort to solve this problem yourself. It is simple to look at the Perl documentation and understand what the original code is doing. If you know Python then you can write your own implementation. If you have made a significant attempt to do this yourself then please show what you have tried and we will gladly help you. It is sometimes effective, but always bad manners, to bring a problem to Stack Overflow and expect a solution to be written for you without any effort on your part.

Comment: @MikeMayer67: no, the original is limited to 16 characters (and will deal differently with an odd number of characters < 16 than your code does)

Comment: @ysth: I realize this.  That's why I made the comment that my version ignores the 8 byte restriction of the original code.  Yes, because it processes characters, this really is 16 bytes. But if you look at the apparent intent of this being a hexadecimal number, then each pair of characters represents a byte.  It was in this interpretation that I stated the original code was limited to 8 bytes.

Comment: @ChangoMango.  Clearly, you have not actually "thrown" a value at the posted perl sub or you did not post what you are actually working with.  There is no way that passing cdc4b28e1504ca01 to the posted sub will return 128920029968385229.